# Post data from form with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Another newbie propblem. I want to post a post with my form. I have Post.js that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import PostForm from './PostFormContainer';

export class Post extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    posts: PropTypes.any,
    fetchPosts: PropTypes.func,
    sendPostData: PropTypes.func,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchPosts } = this.props;
    fetchPosts();
  }

  // onSubmit = (e, id, title, body) => {
  //   e.preventDefault();
  //   axios
  //     .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  //       id,
  //       title,
  //       body,
  //     })
  //     .then(res =>
  //       this.setState({
  //         posts: [...this.state.posts, res.data],
  //       })
  //     );
  // };

  // onSubmit(e, id, title, body) {
  //   e.preventDefault();
  //   console.log('data');
  //   console.log('data', id);
  //   console.log('data', title);
  //   console.log('data', body);

  //   this.props.sendPostData(id, title, body);
  //   console.log('sendPostData', this.props.sendPostData(id, title, body));
  // }

  render() {
    console.log('props', this.props);
    const { posts } = this.props;
    if (!posts.length) {
      return (
        <div>
          <PostForm addPost={this.onSubmit} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <PostForm addPost={this.onSubmit} />
          <br />

          <div>
            {posts.map(post => (
              <div key={post.id}>
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                <p>{post.body}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
            ;
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Where I have `<PostForm addPost={this.onSubmit} />`
My PostForm.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class PostForm extends Component {
  ///state = {
   // title: '',
   // body: '',
  //};

  static propTypes = {
    posts: PropTypes.any,
    // fetchPosts: PropTypes.func,
    sendPostData: PropTypes.func,
  };

  //onChange = e => {
    //this.setState({
      // e.target.name zawsze będzie targetował pole z value i zmieniał jego stan
     // [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
   // });
  //};

  // onSubmit(e, id, title, body) {
  //   e.preventDefault();

  //   console.log('data');
  //   console.log('data', id);
  //   console.log('data', title);
  //   console.log('data', body);
  // }

  onSubmit(e, id, title, body) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('data');
    console.log('data', id);
    console.log('data', title);
    console.log('data', body);
    // const post = {
    //   title,
    //   body,
    // };

    this.props.sendPostData(title, body);
    // console.log('sendPostData', this.props.sendPostData(post));
  }

  render() {
    console.log('props form', this.props);
    const { title, body } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Add Post </h1>
        <form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e, title, body)}>
          <div>
            <label>Title: </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              name='title'
              value={title}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Body: </label>
            <textarea name='body' value={body} onChange={this.onChange} />
          </div>
          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostForm;
```

Here I want to send this with my action.
I have two container files
PostFormContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import { sendPost } from '../reducers/postReducers';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  sendPostData: post => dispatch(sendPost(post)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostForm);
```

and PostContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Post from './Post';
import { fetchFromApi } from '../reducers/postReducers';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchPosts: () => dispatch(fetchFromApi()),
  // sendPostData: (id, title, body) => dispatch(sendPost({ id, title, body })),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

and my reducer

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const reducerName = 'posts';
const createActionName = name => `/${reducerName}/${name}`;

/* action type */

const FETCH_POSTS = createActionName('FETCH_POSTS');
const SUBMIT_POST = createActionName('SUBMIT_POST');

/* action creator */
export const fetchStarted = payload => ({ payload, type: FETCH_POSTS });
export const submitPost = payload => ({ payload, type: SUBMIT_POST });

/* thunk */
export const fetchFromApi = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=5').then(
      res => dispatch(fetchStarted(res.data))
      // console.log('res', res)
      // console.log('res data', res.data)
    );
  };
};

export const sendPost = (postId, postTitle, postBody) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    Axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
      id: postId,
      title: postTitle,
      body: postBody,
    }).then(res => {
      dispatch(submitPost(res.data));
    });
  };
};

/* reducer */
export default function reducer(state = [], action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return action.payload;
    case SUBMIT_POST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Right now my console.logs shows that all my data is undefined. Not sure what the I am missing, but I can't solve this.

Here is also my stro.js

```
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import postReducer from './reducers/postReducers';

const initialState = {
  posts: {
    data: {},
  },
};

const reducers = {
  posts: postReducer,
};

Object.keys(initialState).forEach(item => {
  if (typeof reducers[item] == 'undefined') {
    reducers[item] = (state = null) => state;
  }
});

const combinedReducers = combineReducers(reducers);

const store = createStore(
  combinedReducers,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Your PostForm element accepts `body` as a prop, but you don't seem to be sending a `body` prop to it...

Comment: This is just my opinion and I don't know your entire use case, but is there a good reason you're tying the content of your form into Redux state? Does any other part of your app need to know, or permanently store, the information the user types into that form text input? Because in my opinion, most React form inputs should be filled with a DefaultValue prop and you should be submitting a `FormData` to the api, rather than trying to control everything with state or redux

Comment: There is no special case. I'm just trying different things.

Comment: Fair enough. If you want to use `this.props.body` in your Component to decide what gets sent in the request, you need to set the `body` prop somewhere, whether that's in the place you use your component, or in your Redux connector, somewhere

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that :) i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PostForm` element uses props `title` and `body`, but the place where you use `PostForm` doesn't send it a `body` or `title` prop.

I don't know your particular use case, but in React/Redux there are two ways to send a property to an element:

```
<PostForm body={this.state.postFormBody} title={this.state.postFormTitle} />
```

Or by using your Redux connector, mapStateToProps function, and returning an object with 'body' and 'title' keys that match something in your Redux store